# Solving $5\times9^x-8\times15^x+3\times25^x>0$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, factoring

**Question:** Solve the inequality:

$5\times9^x-8\times15^x+3\times25^x>0$

So far I have managed to factorise the inequality:

$(5\times3^x-3\times5^x)(3^x-5^x)>0$

From here on, I am stuck.

I would very much appreciate it if you could answer this exam question and lay the working out as if it were an exam. I have an answer from the solutions book so can tell you if your answer is correct using that. Many thanks.

Comment: Divide the first parenthesis by $15$ and use the fact $3^t-5^t<0\Leftrightarrow t>0$ when considering cases $(<0)\cdot(<0)\,>0$ and $(>0)\cdot(>0)\,>0$.

Comment: How is this quadratic?

Comment: This is also a nice problem with algebra.

Comment: First, please pay attention to your tags and make sure all of them are relevant to the question. In addition, words like 'tough' in the title do not tell us very much, so either omit them or write the full question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve your inequality by transforming it into a sign problem for a quadratic function dividing by $15^x= 3^x\cdot 5^x$:

$$5\times9^x-8\times15^x+3\times25^x>0 \Leftrightarrow 5\left(\frac 35\right)^x - 8 + 3\left(\frac 53\right)^x>0$$

Setting $t = \left(\frac 35\right)^x$ you only need to solve

$$5t+\frac 3t - 8 >0 \text{ for } t>0$$

or equivalently
$$5t^2 - 8t + 3 = (5t-3)(t-1)>0$$

So, you get either

$$1<t= \left(\frac 35\right)^x \Leftrightarrow \boxed{x<0}$$

or

$$\frac 35 > t =\left(\frac 35\right)^x \Leftrightarrow \boxed{x>1}$$

Answer (score 1):

When both factors are positive, the intersection of $x < 0$ and $x < 1$ is $x < 0$. But when both factors of $(5\times3^x-3\times5^x)(3^x-5^x)$ are negative, their product is still positive, so we must consider this case as well.

$5\times3^x-3\times5^x < 0$ gives $\left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^{x-1} < \left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^{0}$ like before. However, since $3/5 < 1$, the $y$-values are getting smaller as the $x$-values increase. Drawing a sketch of the exponential function and the curve, the inequality sign flips to give $x - 1 > 0, x > 1$.

Similarly, $3^x - 5^x < 0$ leads to $3^x < 5^x$ or $\left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^x < \left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^{0}$, and the inequality sign flips again, thus $x > 0$. Since both factors need to be negative for the product to be positive, we need to take the intersection of $x > 1, x > 0$ which is $x > 1$.

Altogether, we have $x < 0$ and $x > 1$.

Comment: The mark scheme gives the following answer ]0,1[... Is this equivalent to what you have found above?

Comment: Assuming that $]0, 1[$ means $(0, 1)$, no that is not correct. You can verify this answer is correct using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yykfxxyvk0).

Answer (score 0):

The first factor is positive when
$$5 \cdot 3^x - 3 \cdot 5^x > 0$$
divide by $15$ to get
$$3^{x-1} - 5^{x-1} > 0$$
$$3^{x-1} > 5^{x-1}$$
$$\frac{3^{x-1}}{5^{x-1}} >1$$
$$\left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^{x-1} >\left( \frac{3}{5}\right)^{0}$$
$$x-1<0$$
$$x<1$$

In a similar way you can show that the second factor is positive when $x<0$.

Hence the solution is $$x<0 \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad x>1$$

Comment: You say x<1 at one point but then x>1 at the end? Is this a mistake?

Comment: This is a mistake. When both factors are positive, we have the intersection of $x < 0$ and $x < 1$ as $x < 0$, but both factors can be negative and their product will still be greater than $0$.

Comment: @TobyMak The mark scheme gives the following answer ]0,1[... Is this equivalent to what we have found above?

Comment: $]0,1[$ denotes numbers between $0$ and $1$, namely $0<x<1$. It's the solution of the opposite inequality. I am sure my solution is correct, while $]0,1[$ is incorrect. The other answers agree with mine.